# Apple notarization fails with install4j generated DMG

Tags: install4j, notarize

Struggling to notarize DMG created with **install4j v8.0.8**. This is what I do:

- the install4j runs on Windows machine
- we use "MacOS folder archive" media packaged into DMG
- everything is signed as required with valid "Developer ID Application" certificate
- the DMG then taken to MacOS machine (Big Sur) where we do notarization with our own scripts
- notarization fails with an error "**The signature of the binary is invalid**" pointing to one specific file

When I check the signature of that binary with Mac tools it looks perfectly fine. When I check the signature of the DMG, it looks fine too:

```
$ codesign -vd --verbose=4 path-to-failed-binary
$ codesign -vvv --deep --display path-to.dmg
```

When I remove this particular binary from the package, the app gets notarized fine (there are many other binaries inside the package, like JRE). Looking around I see similar problems related to [the way the package is zipped](https://blog.frostwire.com/2019/08/27/apple-notarization-the-signature-of-the-binary-is-invalid-one-other-reason-not-explained-in-apple-developer-documentation/).

Which makes me wander if it even possible to create DMG on Windows machines with install4j and then doing the manual notarization on Mac? Or, there is something wrong in install4j creating the DMG package?

Comment: Yes, you can sign on Windows and notarize on macOS. install4j may not correctly sign some external binaries, but that would not depend on the OS where build the installer.

Comment: @IngoKegel - OK, so how do I find out what isn't signed correctly in the DMG produced and signed on Windows by install4j 8.0.8?  Apple notarization rejects this DMG, I have no idea why..

Comment: codesign should tell you, if not, nobody knows. Another idea; Is this binary already signed? Then I would try to remove the signature and let install4j sign it.

Comment: @IngoKegel, How can a signature be removed? Originally this binary is signed with Eclipse Foundation signature (it's an RCP application). Then it gets signed with install4j which applies my Apple Developer ID Application. And that is what I see as valid signature with codesign tool. I want to try to remove the original Eclipse signature.. no idea how

Comment: Remove the `Contents/_CodeSignature` folder in the application bundle.

Comment: there is no such folder

Comment: https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/13622/remove-code-signature-from-a-mac-binary